# How to Column Span using Apache POI for parsing XLS?

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

In the Above pic  Row1 contains  Col1 and Col2

Row2  contains  few variables .

My Requirement , Using Apache POI is there way or an API  where i can get  the

If i say Col1  i need to get the list of var1 to var4 (Note: It can be dynamic since i am parsing the file).

Similarly for Col2  var5 to var10

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking - you might want to edit the question so that the diagram at the top is formatted with a fixed width font (eg in a code block) so it's easier to see

Comment: @Gagravarr  Hope you understood my question  you need still i can explain it .. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close.  Use the HSSFSheet.getMergedRegion(int index) method to get a reference to a merged region.  That returns a CellRangeAddress, for which you can call getNumberOfCells() which should get you pretty close.

You need to know which merged regions you are after, you can get the total number of them using HSSFSheet.getNumMergedRegions().  It's still possible that there may be a merged region other than your headers, this is just a matter of your input format.

Here is a link to the POI API: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

The notable classes are HSSFSheet and CellRangeAddress